# Postgres Changing column from TEXT to INTEGER increases table size

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres table that has a schema like this

```
                                              Table "am.old_product"
     Column      |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-----------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 p_config_sku    | text                     |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 p_simple_sku    | text                     |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 p_merchant_id   | text                     |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 p_country       | character varying(2)     |           |          |         | extended |              | 
 p_discount_rate | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_black_price   | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_red_price     | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_received_at   | timestamp with time zone |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 p_event_id      | uuid                     |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 p_is_deleted    | boolean                  |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "product_p_simple_sku_p_country_p_merchant_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (p_simple_sku, p_country, p_merchant_id)
    "config_sku_country_idx" btree (p_config_sku, p_country)
```

We decided that it would be a better idea remove the TEXT field merchant_id and move it to another table, and reference it in the product table using a foreign key. So the new schema looks just like this.

```
                                                  Table "am.product"
      Column       |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 p_config_sku      | text                     |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 p_simple_sku      | text                     |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 p_country         | character varying(2)     |           | not null |         | extended |              | 
 p_discount_rate   | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_black_price     | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_red_price       | numeric(10,2)            |           |          |         | main     |              | 
 p_received_at     | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 p_event_id        | uuid                     |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 p_is_deleted      | boolean                  |           |          | false   | plain    |              | 
 p_merchant_id_new | integer                  |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "new_product_p_simple_sku_p_country_p_merchant_id_new_idx" UNIQUE, btree (p_simple_sku, p_country, p_merchant_id_new)
    "p_config_sku_country_idx" btree (p_config_sku, p_country)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_merchant_id" FOREIGN KEY (p_merchant_id_new) REFERENCES am.merchant(m_id)
```

Now this should make the product table size drop right? we are using a 4 bytes integer instead of a TEXT. Well not really, the two tables, have the same exact number of rows. The product table (one with integer field) size is 34.3 GB. While the old table's size (with TEXT) has size of 19.7GB

Does anyone have an explanation for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a wild guess you have done this with various ALTER TABLE commands forcing at least one rewrite of the entire table.

The unused space will be gradually re-used, or for a more prompt change try a `CLUSTER` or `VACUUM FULL` on the table.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [VACUUM](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html) command.

A database file is an organized collection of tuples. A row can be made up of one or more tuples. When you added a new column, you added tuples to the table file. But when you dropped a column, the space occupied by the tuples remains, because to delete it from the file is a costly operation. They are dead tuples.

```
 VACUUM FULL am.product;
```

This will unfortunately will create exclusive locks on the table, and you won't be able to query it in the process.